# Is using 賜る correct when listening to or accepting a condition?

Tags: word-choice, keigo

From ひぐらしのなく頃に。The 園崎 clan (sort of mafia, no spoilers please!) are negotiating the handover of a scrap book to the police, in return for the police cancelling a search/raid of a building.

刑事「（...）この度の一斉捜査は見送らせていただきます」
園崎「ありがとうございます。（...）」
刑事「約束に従い、このスクラップ帳は警察でお預かりします。それから条件が２つ。」
園崎「**賜ります**」
刑事「一点目は、この場にないスクラップ帳を園崎家が入手した場合、速やかに警察に提出すること。（...）」

I have googled and 賜る appears to be a humble version of （物を）もらう・いただく. For 聞く・受ける type meanings,　承る seems more correct. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4):

In terms of common usage, you are right. 承ります would be much more normal here. But 賜る could be used for receiving abstract things, like 条件. In that sense, it shouldn't be completely wrong.

I believe light novel authors sometimes consciously deviate from common usage or use rare words just in order to sound cool, and 賜る here is just one instance.